If a group G does not act freely on a scheme X, is the quotient sheaf X/G not an algebraic space?
Lemma 66.34.1 of the Stacks project states the following:
Let S be a scheme. Let X be an algebraic space over S. Let G be an abstract group with a free action on X. Then the quotient sheaf X/G is an algebraic space.
The quotient sheaf X/G is the sheafification in the étalé topology of the following presheaf:
$$\underline{Schemes} \longrightarrow \underline{Sets}: T \longmapsto X(T)/G$$
As the quotient sheaf can always be defined, can we also prove that X/G is NOT an algebraic space if the group does NOT act freely?

What if $G$ acts trivially?

@AlexYoucis good point. I guess I was hoping to say why this quotient sheaf is not that interesting to model some sort of geometric quotient of X by G, and the quotient stack does model it neatly.

Doesn’t the quotient always exist as an algebraic space (if $X$ is separated)? Like here’s generalization of this result. https://people.kth.se/~dary/quotients20070824.pdf

@AlexYoucis Your reference seems to also assume that G is finite (which I don't want to assume). The article does state the following in Thm 2.15: "As X/R is a categorical quotient in the category of sheaves on the fppf topology, it is a categorical quotient in the category of algebraic spaces. " Is this a well-known fact for fppf topology? Does it also hold for etale topology (or Zariski if we restrict to schemes)?
